# Show the Dimension of a Finite Vector Space is Even

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, linear-transformations, diagonalization

Let $V$ be a finite-dimensional vector space over a field $\mathbb{F}$ of characteristic $\ne 2$. Let $X,Y: V \rightarrow V$ be linear transformations such that $X^2=Y^2=\rm Id$, where $\rm Id$ is the identity transformation.

Suppose that $XY=-YX$. Show that $\dim V$ is even, and that there is a basis of $V$ in which the matrices of $X$ and $Y$ are $$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ I_n & 0\end{bmatrix} \quad \& \quad \begin{bmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ 0 & -I_n\end{bmatrix}$$ respectively, where $I_n$ is the identity matrix and $\dim V=2n$.

Things I know:

I've showed that both $X$ and $Y$ are diagonalizable with eigenvalues $\lambda= \pm 1$.

I have also thought the since $X,Y$ are diagonalizable, we may use the Jordan canonical form. But from here, I'm not sure how to proceed.

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: It seems what your problem is really saying: let $X,Y$ be representations of elements of (/which ultimately generate) the Dihedral group of order 8.  Working over $\mathbb C$ first, confirm that this must be a direct sum of the sole order 2 irreducible representation.  Then confirm the following are valid matrix representations for $X$ and $Y$.  Finally confirm the matrix representation holds over arbitrary field of characteristic $\neq 2$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the relation $XY=-YX$, you get that if $y$ is an eigenvector associated with eigenvalue $1$ of $Y$

$$X(Y(y))= X(y) =-YX(y)= -Y(X(y))$$ which means that $X(y))$ is an eigenvector associated with the eigenvalue $-1$ of $Y$. As we suppose that the characteristic of the field is not equal to $2$ ($1 \neq -1$), the two eigenvalues are distinct and the vectors $y, X(y)$ are linearly independent.

From this, you can build by induction a family of vectors $\{y_1, \dots, y_n\}$ that is a basis of the eigenspace $E_Y(1)$ associated to the eigenvalue $1$ of $Y$, and such that $\{y_1, \dots, y_n, X(y_1), \dots, X(y_n)\}$ is a basis of $V$. Therefore the dimension of the vector space is even. Let say $2n$.

Now let's have a look at the matrices of $X$ and $Y$ in the basis

$$e_1 = y_1, \dots, e_n = y_n, e_{n+1}= X(y_1), \dots, e_{2n}= X(y_n)$$

For $1 \le i \le n$ we have

$$\begin{cases}
X(e_i) &= X(y_i) = e_{i+n}\\
X(e_{i+n}) &= X(X(y_{i})) =X^2(y_{i})=y_{i} = e_i\\
Y(e_i) &= Y(y_i)=y_i=e_i\\
Y(e_{i+n}) &=  Y(X(y_i)) = -X(y_i)=-e_{i+n}
\end{cases}$$

which is exactly the relations
$$\begin{bmatrix} 0 & I_n \\ I_n & 0\end{bmatrix} \quad \& \quad \begin{bmatrix} I_n & 0 \\ 0 & -I_n\end{bmatrix}$$ we're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I see that  $x_1, \cdots, x_n, Y(x_1), \cdots, Y(x_n)$ is  a basis for $V$. But I'm still unsure how to get the matrix form of $X$ and $Y$ from there. Could you please elaborate more on that part?

Comment: @Korn I updated the answer with more details.

Comment: Think there's a typo here. I believe that the first part of the first equation should say $X(Y(y)) = X(y) = \cdots$.

Comment: @MathFrak96 Thanks for spotting the istake. I updated the answer.